# integration testing api having fluent validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, fluentvalidation

I have API which uses FluentValidations.

I am writing integration test and wanted to assert that bad request response contains error field name and messages.  I want to check for fieldname, and message and ensure they are same as returned from fluentvalidations.   Am getting a json response filled with validation errors but not sure into which object should i deserialize into.

```
response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<?>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
result.Should().BeOfType<?>();
result.Should().NotBeNull();
result.Should().HaveCount(something);
```

sample response is fluentvalidation response

```
{
  "Name": [
    "Name is required.",
    "Name length cannot be more that 255 chars"
  ],
  "ListTypeId": [
    "Invalid listtypeid"
  ],
  "PartyRoleId": [
    "Invalid partyroleid"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Give an example of what the json response content looks like

Comment: updated.  its basic raw response that comes out of fluentvalidation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the provided JSON example a `IDictionary<string,string[]>` should be able to satisfy that model

```
response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string,string[]>>(json);
result.Should().BeOfType<IDictionary<string,string[]>>();
result.Should().NotBeNull();
result.Should().HaveCount(something);
```

Comment: ah. thank you so much..  i am sorry i gave up so early..  i should have figured it out.